# alternative of jbrowse on centos

Tags: centos6, perl-module, genome, google-genomics, jbrowse

Is there an **alternative Software of JBrowse** (on Centos6).

I need to integrate one into my webpage, but jbrowse is giving error of zlib while installing PerlIO::gzip. Although all related modules (libpng,libpng-devel,gd-devel,zlib-devel,perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker,Development Tools, perl-Compress-Zlib) are installed.

Any suggestion will be helpful.
An alternative for windows8 os will also work.

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is a mailing list cross link for the JBrowse issue here here https://sourceforge.net/p/gmod/mailman/message/36349221/

Alternatives to JBrowse could include igv.js, pileup.js, genomeview, or other HTML5 genome browsers

Also note, if we take the stance that Perl pre-requisites really are impossible to install on your system, then we can take an alternative approach because JBrowse does not actually require Perl pre-requisites to be installed for operation. Modern JBrowse can load native file formats without using the Perl scripts for conversion.

In this case, you can simply create file directory like

```
data/genome.fa
data/genome.fa.fai
data/tracks.conf
data/annotations.sorted.gff.gz
data/annotations.sorted.gff.gz.tbi
```

where genome.fa.fai is generated by `samtools faidx genome.fa` and annotations.sorted.gff.gz is generated by `sort -k1,1 -k4,4n annotations.gff > annotations.sorted.gff` and then `bgzip annotations.sorted.gff.gz` and finally `tabix -p vcf annotations.sorted.gff.gz`

Then the tracks.conf file can contain

```
[GENERAL]
refSeqs=genome.fa.fai

[tracks.refseq]
urlTemplate=genome.fa
storeClass=JBrowse/Store/SeqFeature/IndexedFasta
type=Sequence
[tracks.annotations]
urlTemplate=annotations.sorted.gz
type=CanvasFeatures
storeClass=JBrowse/Store/SeqFeature/GFF3Tabix
```

In this sense, your browser can be fully created without perl pre-requisites